# Choosing the largest date from the query DB2

Tags: sql, db2

How can I choose the largest / maximum date from the following query?

```
SELECT 
s.PROFILENUMBER AS profile
a.AUTHTYPE AS authorization_type,
to_char(date(a.wr), 'yyyymmdd') AS ts_vf,
to_char(date(c.wr), 'yyyymmdd') AS ts_vf,
to_char(date(s.wr), 'yyyymmdd') AS ts_vf,
FROM ssn_an_auth a,
ssn_an_spac_c c,
ssn_an_salesprofile s
where a.id = c.aaid
and s.id = c.ssid
```

Comment: Show sample data and expected result. Question is ambiguous.

Comment: does `MAX()` not work for you?

Comment: Your query outputs not dates, although it does convert three dates into strings.  Hence, your question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT MAX(MAX(a_wr,c_wr,s_wr)) AS "largest / maximum date" FROM (
    SELECT 
    s.PROFILENUMBER AS profile,
    a.AUTHTYPE AS authorization_type,
    date(a.wr) a_wr,
    date(c.wr) c_wr,
    date(s.wr) s_wr
    FROM ssn_an_auth a,
    ssn_an_spac_c c,
    ssn_an_salesprofile s
    where a.id = c.aaid
    and s.id = c.ssid
)
```